# Why does strcpy read extra characters?

Tags: c, tree

I just have a question(s) about making a binary tree, as this code doesn't work, it places nodes where they shouldn't go, and although it never crashes its leaking memory like a busted pipe. The idea was a simple guessing game where it simply tries to guess what you are thinking about, and when it gets it wrong you enter a question and answer to help it learn. Relevant code:

I guess my primary problem is char *guess will sometimes store only fragments of the original string passed to getnew(). The next would be the logic in traverse(), as it will jump to the "no" condition regardless of user input.

```
struct binary {
    unsigned long ID;
    char *guess;
    char isAns;
    struct binary *yes;
    struct binary *no;
};
typedef struct binary Node;

void traverse(Node **top)
{
    if(*top)
    {    
        char ans[128] = "ok";
        char ans2[128] = "ok";
        if((*top)->isAns=='y')
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"Is it %s (y/n)? ",(*top)->guess);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"%s (y/n)? ",(*top)->guess);
        }
        while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
        if((*top)->isAns=='y')
        {
            if(ans=="y")
            {
                printf("Successful string of guesses!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter another question to figure out the difference: ");
                while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
                Node *q=getnew(ans,'n');
                printf("Enter the right answer: ");
                while(!fgets(ans2,128,stdin));
                push1(top,q,'n');
                (*top)->yes = getnew(ans2,'y');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(ans=="y")
            {
                if((*top)->yes)
                {
                    traverse(&(*top)->yes);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Null node for top->yes\n");
                    printf("Enter an answer: ");
                    while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
                    (*top)->yes=getnew(ans,'y');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if((*top)->no)
                {
                    traverse(&(*top)->no);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Null node for top->no\n");
                    printf("Enter an answer: ");
                    while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
                    (*top)->no=getnew(ans,'y');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        char ques[128] = "ok";
        char ans[128] = "ok";
        printf("Node is null\n");
        printf("Put in a question and answer to yes condition\n");
        printf("Enter question: ");
        while(!fgets(ques,128,stdin));
        printf("Enter answer for yes condition: ");
        while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
        (*top) = getnew(ques,'n');
        (*top)->yes=getnew(ans,'y');
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}



Node * getnew(char *msg, char isAns)
{
    Node *nnew = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nnew->ID=clock();
    nnew->guess=malloc(sizeof(msg));
    strcpy(nnew->guess,msg);
    nnew->isAns=isAns;
    nnew->yes=0;
    nnew->no=0;
    return nnew;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `sizeof(msg)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: "it never crashes" -- your bad luck; that strcpy is undefined behavior. "ts leaking memory like a busted pipe" -- perhaps because there's no `free` in the posted code?

Comment: @Jim wow that sizeof thing seems obvious. Also, that's not the entire code. I have destroy_branch() and destroy_node methods() I didn't include it because its not central to program function (ok, ok I know what your thinking... I was smart enough to take that into account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)

C strings are `char *` pointers, therefore `sizeof(msg) == sizeof(char*) == 8 or 4".  Not what you want.

```
nnew->guess=malloc(sizeof(msg));
strcpy(nnew->guess,msg);
```

Should be

```
nnew->guess = strdup(msg);
```

Or
    nnew->guess=malloc(strlen(msg) + 1);
    strcpy(nnew->guess,msg + 1);

The +1 is for the nul termintor (assuming you want it).

Comment: Ok, if I had been actually reading instead of writing my answer would be "What @Michael Burr said"

Answer (score 3):

`nnew->guess=malloc(sizeof(msg));` only allocates enough memory for a pointer.

Instead of:

```
nnew->guess=malloc(sizeof(msg));
strcpy(nnew->guess,msg);
```

use:

```
nnew->guess=strdup(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see where `guess` is `malloc`ed but I don't see where it's `free`d.  That would definitely cause memory leaks.

---

as a side note, I've just spun up a quick program to check into the

```
nnew->guess=malloc(sizeof(msg));
```

it looks like this

```
char str[10] = "string";
printf("%d", sizeof(str));
```

and surprisingly, it printed `10`,

but that method of allocation still makes me uneasy.

Comment: No surprise, `str` is a 10-byte array.  But the weird stuff happens when you make a typedef.  IIRC if  `sizeof(TypeArrayOf100Bytes) == sizeof(char*)`.  Even though `sizeof(VarArrayOf100Bytes)` == 100.  Go figure.

Comment: So neither of you are familiar enough with C to know what sizeof does? Nothing at all weird happens as a result of typedefs.